# DZNEmptyDataSet not working for Collection View?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

As it says in the title I am using DZNEmptyDataSet library with a UICollection view. 
For tableview controller, we have the following in `viewDidLoad`:

```
   self.tableView.emptyDataSetSource = self
   tableView.emptyDataSetDelegate = self
   tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

but what about the Collection view?
There does not seem to be anything similar to `tableFooterView`.

What is the right way to go about doing this?

Comment: UICollectionViews don't use dedicated footers, they use "supplementary views".